# 'Out of Range' error setting up dual monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a brand new digital HP Windows 10 laptop connected through a HDMI to VGA adapter to a 1680x1050 resolution analog monitor and I want them to work as dual monitors. In 'Display Settings' menu laptop's screen appears as monitor 1 and the analog monitor as monitor 2.

Well, the thing is that if I run 'Show Desktop Only on 1' or 'Show Desktop Only on 2' in 'Display Settings', both monitors look perfectly but when I click on 'Extend This Displays', monitor 1 (laptop's screen) continues looking good while monitor 2 (analog monitor), with the same '1680x1050 (recommended)' resoluton set in 'Display Settings' as before, its image narrows on the screen, with blurry text and a 'Out of Range' monitor error.

Do you have any ideas to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you need to scale down your dpi for the display(s). Too high a range in the settings for the monitor or grapics card. Try 1920 x 1080

Comment: Thanks, @vssher. In 1920x1080 resolution, 'Out of Range' monitor error is still there as well as the blurry text.

Comment: With an analog monitor 60 Hertz is too low, you need to set the mode (list all modes) in display properties, to a higher setting, say in about 80 Hertz. Sometimes it helps to restart the computer after you make the settings. It think you need a digital monitor to work with, laptops today do not like analog monitors, neither does Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved it. In fact, it was very simple but I had to know a few steps to solve this issue :

1. Right Click on the home screen > click on display settings
2. Go to the bottom of the window and click on advanced display settings
3. Click on display adapter properties for display 2
4. Click on the last tab intel HD Graphics control panel
5. On the Display select options choose monitor
6. On the Scaling select options choose Customize Aspect Ratio
7. Click Apply :) , that’s it

Source: https://es.ifixit.com/Respuestas/Ver/385263/Second+Monitor+says+out+of+range#answer572883

Thank you anyway!

Comment: You should mark the answer as solved so that others may be helped by it, also, you would earn more points. Glad you solved it. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

You helped me on the way,. my solution was only a bit different.

I selected a higher frequency, 75hz and changed resolution later.
This can be found in:

1. advanced display settings.
2. Display adaptor properties for display 2.
3. on the adaptor tap,.
   List all modes,. select a higher frequency.

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

I had a extra screen attached via VGA > Hdmi cable to  a Laptop.  The screen displayed "Out of Range" try "1280 * 1024 - 60Hz" even after trying to disable the graphics card and set "Base video" option via msconfig > Boot, in Safe Mode.
This worked:

1. Go to Settings > System > Display;
2. Choose the Extended or Duplicate screen from dropdown;
3. At the bottom of the screen click "Advanced display settings";
4. Choose the display that shows the "Out of Range" message;
5. Click "Display adapter properties for DisplayX";
6. Click "List All Modes" at the bottom and choose the option expected by the screen and "Apply".